# C++, binaries, makefile and .mk

Tags: c++, eclipse-photon

I recently decided to download eclipse photon for C++ development. I have never written a C++ or C program before. I started a new project and they have a pre-built hello world program that I went with just to check it out.

I noticed in the Project Explorer that there is the main src folder but there is also a folder called Debug and inside it is another src folder which includes: makefile, objects.mk and sources.mk.

On top of that there is a Binaries folder (or file?) not really sure what any of this stuff is. I read a few things about the makefile essentially its so others can easily compile your code, correct? However, the rest of these files: objects.mk, sources.mk and the binaries file (folder?) what are these for?

Comment: A makefile is mostly so that *you* can easily compile your code. The other files objects.mk and sources.mk are also makefiles. IIRC they are kind of sub-makefiles that are includes or invoked by the main makefile.

Comment: The Binaries folder is virtual. It gathers all of the binaries that are inside the project folders into one place so you can find them easily. The binaries themselves will wind up in the root of the Release and Debug folders (or the folders for any other configurations you define for the project) after they are successfully built. The makefile, objects.mk and sources.mk.files John covered. These are be useful as you can run them on their own without the Eclipse GUI and get the same results by typing `make` in the appropriate folder.